# Hook into the Admin Dashboard and redirect users

Tags: query, admin, api

So I have a configuration that a API returns a `?code=.....` to the URL inside my admin dashboard `www.test.com/wp-admin`.

Is there a hook inside the admin where I can copy the admin url `www.test.com/wp-admin?code=...` and redirect to a settings page?

I'm not asking to write code, I just want to be able to know if it's possible to determine if a query string is present on the admin page, to then redirect the user to a settings page.

Example:

API response returns back `www.test.com/wp-admin?code=...`

Copy the `?code` response and redirect user to `www.test.com/wp-admin?page=instagram` and apply the `?code=...` response as `www.test.com/wp-admin?page=instagram&code=....`.

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're looking to do that can be done with functions to either check the URL for parameters and change PHP header location, or keep them on the same URL but change their reflected information using add_rewrite_rule()

Comment: @couchwood, what's the best way to determine if a user is on `/wp-admin`?

Comment: if(is_admin()) {} or using the WP global $pagenow would be two ways I'd recommend going about that

Comment: @couchwood, woot! is_admin helped out so much! Is there a way to target `/wp-admin/options-general.php` specifically?

Comment: I would check out this stackoverflow question [Check if URL has certain string with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118823/check-if-url-has-certain-string-with-php)